# How to view Unity method implementations in VSCode "Jump To Definition"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have a friend using JetBrains Rider and when he uses **Jump To Definition (F12)** he can see the method signature *and* implementation! I tried installing Rider but it is not yet supported on my ARM64 Mac. Is there anyway I can view Unity method implementations using VSCode or VSCode Insiders?

For example, if I have the following call, I click `Translate`

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * zSpeed);
```

Then I press **F12**, which opens `Transform.cs` but only shows the method headers. The implementations are missing

```
// Summary:
//     Moves the transform by x along the x axis, y along the y axis, and z along the
//     z axis.
//
// Parameters:
//   x:
//
//   y:
//
//   z:
//
//   relativeTo:
public void Translate(float x, float y, float z);

// comments removed for brevity...
public void Translate(float x, float y, float z, [DefaultValue("Space.Self")] Space relativeTo);

// comments removed for brevity...
public void Translate(Vector3 translation);

// comments removed for brevity...
public void Translate(Vector3 translation, [DefaultValue("Space.Self")] Space relativeTo);

// comments removed for brevity...
public void Translate(float x, float y, float z, Transform relativeTo);

// comments removed for brevity...
public void Translate(Vector3 translation, Transform relativeTo);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Per a comment, I tried **Cmd+F12**

[image: cmd-f12]

But then it says **"no implementation found"**

[image: no-implementation]

I'm stuck!

Comment: ctrl + f12 goes to implementations. Left click on the method name should give you the options available with the correspondong shortcuts. Among them, there is the go to implemetation

Comment: thanks! I see "go to implementations" but it says "no implementation found". any ideas? I updated my post.

Comment: You can't see the built-in implementations of Unity since they are in the DLL and not open source ^^ (at least not all of them) what you get is at best the auto-decompiled interface (all public properties, fields and methods) but not how they are implemented ... Actually what do you need the implementation of Unity built-in types for exactly?

Comment: You'll need to add a setting to omnisharp to allow it to decompile external assemblies. Check https://www.strathweb.com/2020/05/decompilation-support-in-omnisharp-and-c-extension-for-vs-code/ (not tested this with Unity though)

Comment: @derHugo i watched my friend's stream and his JetBrains Rider definitely shows the implementations

Comment: Again - I use Rider myself - it shows you at best a decompiled version (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html) that often gets close but is not actually the implementation .. also again: what do you need it for exactly?

Comment: @derHugo being able to see the decompiled implementation is a very good learning resource to understand how unity is functioning under the hood. It demystifies the API calls. Anyway, the feature is obviously part of the editor for a reason. We don't need to agree on it. I would like to know how to make it function for my project.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything for VS code that can do the same (at least not that straight forward) .. maybe [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=icsharpcode.ilspy-vscode)? (Never used VS code tbh) .. but you could also just look into the open [Source Code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) if you are interested ;) ... Or well what rider uses is basically a built-in [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/decompiler/)

Comment: @derHugo I hope my answer on this question makes it clear why this is a useful feature to have working in VSCode.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren thanks for the link. I was able to get it working with your help. I am so happy.

Comment: oh boy .. @derHugo have you tried using VSCode ?

Comment: @Fattie nope ^^ as we have Rider there was never the need for VSCode .. actually it seems so tricky to set it up correctly that we decided directly to rather buy Rider which works out of the box ^^

Comment: intriguing @derHugo  we had the opposite experience, I couldn't really get Rider going smoothly so I gave up.  I don't like VS for Unity.  So I tried VS Code and it worked out great.  I am gonna try Rider again when I get a chance

Comment: In the end I spent about an hour of time to get VSCode configured, and the majority of that time was simply learning what the features were called. The actual work was clicking a couple checkboxes seen in the answer below. Decompilation and [Unity Analyzers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/making-our-unity-analyzers-open-source/) are not specific to Rider. It turns out a good amount of Rider features are simply tapping into omnisharp and roslyn.

Answer (score 4):

I enabled the following options in my **C#** plugin for VSCode. Thanks for the pointer, Karl-Johan Sjögren.

[image: csharp extension settings]

[image: decompilation]
[image: roslyn analyzers]

Now when I press **F12** on `transform.Rotate(Vector.forward)` for example, decompilation support allows me to see

[image: transform.Rotation]

This is very beneficial and helps me understand the how Unity handles rotations in different spaces. Also I can begin to understand complex `Quaternion.Euler` knowing how the familiar `translate.Rotate` uses it internally. The same is true for things like `transform.Translate`

[image: transform.Translate]

For example, if I didn't know I could directly manipulate `position` before, now I know `transform.Translate` is a means of doing just that. Being able to get this information at the click of a single button is a game-changer when you compare it to the alternative of alt-tabbing to your browser and doing a text-based search, spending minutes navigating to a specific section of code.